# Detecting API changes/evolution

Tags: java, api, compatibility

I want to measure API evolution for a given Java project, in particular new/renamed classes, new methods, newly deprecated methods, etc.  Is there a tool that detect such changes?

Back in 2007, a [Google GSoc project](http://code.google.com/soc/2007/google/appinfo.html?csaid=A719985157BF799C) was initiated, however, I cannot find the final work.

Comment: Linked question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040693/how-to-identify-a-missing-method-binary-compatibility-in-a-jar-without-running

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use [Clirr](http://clirr.sourceforge.net/) for that, a binary compatibility checker. From the Clirr web site:

> ### What is it?
>
> Clirr is a tool that checks Java
>   libraries for binary and source
>   compatibility with older releases.
>   Basically you give it two sets of jar
>   files and Clirr dumps out a list of
>   changes in the public api. The Clirr
>   Ant task can be configured to break
>   the build if it detects incompatible
>   api changes. In a continuous
>   integration process Clirr can
>   automatically prevent accidental
>   introduction of binary or source
>   compatibility problems.
>
> ...
>
> ### Features
>
> - Report all API changes (currently only partially implemented)
> - Evaluate each change wrt. binary and source compatibility
> - support plain text and XML reports
> - Flexible failure handling (warnings vs. errors, break the build or set
>     error property)

Comment: Clirr looks very outdated as of 2018. I don't think it even works with java 8 compiled jar files.

Comment: The last binary is from 2005

Answer (score 3):

There's also a new API evolution checking tool called [Revapi](http://revapi.org)

Comment: This is awesome tool!!

Answer (score 2):

Btw there seems to be an api-checker in the gwt source code, don't know if that is the product of the mentioned GSoc project.

[GwtJavaApiCompatibilityChecker](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tools/api-checker/) is also used in [build.xml](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/build.xml)

Comment: This is the actual project I was referencing!

Answer (score 2):

Try [japi-compliance-checker](https://github.com/lvc/japi-compliance-checker) tool. It's open-source. The tool shows API changes and detects both backward source (SC) and backward binary (BC) compatibility issues between two jar archives:

```
japi-compliance-checker -old LIB-0.jar -new LIB-1.jar
```

Sample reports for log4j: http://abi-laboratory.pro/java/tracker/timeline/log4j/

[image]

You can find classification of found compatibility problems by severity level in the reports for particular library versions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[JDiff](http://jdiff.sourceforge.net/) is maybe also worth a mentioning.

> JDiff is a Javadoc doclet which
>   generates an HTML report of all the
>   packages, classes, constructors,
>   methods, and fields which have been
>   removed, added or changed in any way,
>   including their documentation, when
>   two APIs are compared. This is very
>   useful for describing exactly what has
>   changed between two releases of a
>   product. Only the API (Application
>   Programming Interface) of each version
>   is compared. It does not compare what
>   the source code does when executed.

As I understood it runs on the sourcefolder of the old version and generates an xml file. The same for the sourcefolder with the new version. Than the two xml-outputs are compared and a changelist compiled. In html-javadoc-api-style

Comment: JDiff runs on the **Javadoc** of the code, not on the code. It is a good companion to Clirr (if you can trust the Javadoc) and it is mentioned in the related projects (http://clirr.sourceforge.net/related.html). But I prefer something that work at the code level.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to try [japicmp](https://github.com/siom79/japicmp).