# How to identify a missing method (Binary Compatibility) in a JAR statically

Tags: java, jar, static-analysis, bytecode, binary-compatibility

I want to verify binary compatibility between 2 JARs.

Following the suggestions in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972087/how-can-i-visualize-jar-not-plugin-dependencies/972199#972199) I used [jboss tattletale](http://www.jboss.org/tattletale) but it can find only missing classes.

How can I find if there are missing methods? Is it possible at all?

E.g.

**"Depends - on" class** Foo depends on Bar (like many other middle class workers)

```
import org.overlyusedclassnames.Bar

public class Foo{
    public void someMethod(){
         Bar tender = new Bar();
         tender.getJohnnyRedLabel();
         tender.getJohnnyBlueLabel(); //this method is new in the Bar class
    }
}
```

**"Compile time" class**

```
package org.overlyusedclassnames;

/** 
 * @Since 1992
 * Changes: added blue and gold Johnny Walker labels
 */

public class Bar {
    public Drink getJohnnyRedLabel(){
         return new JohnyWalkerFactory.get(RedLabel.class);
    }

    public Drink getJohnnyBlackLabel(){
         return new JohnyWalkerFactory.get(BlackLabel.class);
    }

    public Drink getJohnnyGoldLabel(){
         return new JohnyWalkerFactory.get(GoldLabel.class);
    }

    public Drink getJohnnyBlueLabel(){
         return new JohnyWalkerFactory.get(BlueLabel.class);
    }

}
```

Now imagine an **old** Bar jar is accedently replacing the compiled time bar:

**"Runtime time" class**

```
package org.overlyusedclassnames;

/** 
 * @Since 1909
 * Changes: added red and black Johnny Walker labels
 */

public class Bar {
    public Drink getJohnnyRedLabel(){
         return new JohnyWalkerFactory.get(RedLabel.class);
    }

    public Drink getJohnnyBlackLabel(){
         return new JohnyWalkerFactory.get(BlackLabel.class);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to identify the missing method without running it and getting a `NoSuchMethodError`?

---

**Disclaimer**: This is a major rephrasing of my own [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037157/how-to-identify-a-potential-nosuchmethoderror-or-a-linkageerror-in-a-closed-jar), which is undeletable. I chose asking a new question because the rephrasing will render the current 2 answers as quite unrelated to the topic.

Comment: you can comment on the other question that it should be closed, and super users can close it for you

Comment: @Yoni - already did that

Comment: "without running it"=="statically" (in the title of question)

Comment: @developer Are you asking for the question to be edited?   "without running it" seems clear enough to me.

Comment: @Michael - no, I just want to draw attention of the question author and readers to the popular synonym of this term for more efficient googling in the future.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[japi-compliance-checker](https://github.com/lvc/japi-compliance-checker) - backward API/ABI compatibility checker for a Java library:

```
japi-compliance-checker -lib NAME -old OLD.jar -new NEW.jar
```

[image]

[sigtest](https://sigtest.dev.java.net/) - Oracle's SigTest signature testing and API conformance tool

[japitools](http://sab39.netreach.com/Software/Japitools/42/) - test for compatibility between Java APIs

[japi-checker](http://code.google.com/p/japi-checker/) - a java API backward compatibility checker which works at binary level

[revapi](http://revapi.org/) - API analysis and change tracking tool

or manually using javap decompiler:

```
javap OLD.class > OLD.txt
javap NEW.class > NEW.txt
diff -rNau OLD.txt NEW.txt > CHANGES.txt
```

Comment: hello! guys can i have one small example for this. i.e in which basis it's comparing. how can i get all the debug details in screen?

Comment: @picnic4u - use additional `--debug` option of `japi-compliance-checker` tool to generate intermediate javap output to the `debug/` subdirectory.

Comment: thanks alot now i m getting all the details with 1.1.2 version

Answer (score 3):

[**Clirr**](http://clirr.sf.net) - checks Java libraries for binary and source compatibility with older releases:

```
java -jar clirr-core-0.6-uber.jar -o OLD.jar -n NEW.jar
```

Comment: Thanks, why two separate answers by the way?

Comment: @EranMedan Hm, do not remember the reason =)

Answer (score 3):

[Revapi](http://revapi.org) can do the job, too. It is easy to incorporate it into maven builds, which is not your case obviously, but might be of interest to others.

It can also check arbitrary sets of jars using its standalone mode.

Comment: The project does not have any "downloadables" - or, I could not find a link in their primary website

Comment: The download section is now there on the revamped site: http://revapi.org/downloads.html

Answer (score 3):

[japicmp](https://github.com/siom79/japicmp) is another tool for checking binary compatibility. It is available as standalone command line tool or as maven plugin.

Comment: Don't forget to disclose your affiliation with the projects or blogs that you mention in your posts. Please add appropriate disclose to [all three](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2833924+url%3Ajapicmp) of such answers. Also, if you recommend a tool or library, then you should show how it can be applied.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool by the name of [Animal Sniffer](https://www.mojohaus.org/animal-sniffer/) that allows you to extract a signature for an API.  Then it can statically verify that users of the API stick to the signature, and it can statically verify that implementors of the API have everything implemented.   I think this would solve your problem nicely.

You can download the jar for Animal Sniffer from the codehaus maven repository:
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/animal-sniffer/

Comment: @Michael - did you find a download link? where does it hide?

Comment: The tool is written by Maven folks, so I think they just use various maven repositories, which is easy in Maven.  Not so easy in 'ant' unfortunately.

Comment: I haven't tested it yet, but this is the best answer so far, I'll add a comment once I give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a to check a specific class or a generic tool for comparing jar's?
If it's for 1 class, simply load the class in a custom class loader, check the methods signature by using reflection and that's it. If you need it for many JAR's/Classes this will be too much work.